# Google Document AI Python Query Throws "ValueError: Unknown field for ProcessRequest: document_type"... base64 encoding throws another error

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I'm running the sample query for Python using an OCR Google Document AI processor. The only difference between my query and this sample query:

```
process_document_sample(
  project_id="99999FAKE",
  location="us",
  processor_id="99999FAKE",
  file_path="/path/to/local/pdf"
)
```

is that I'm using JPEG instead of PDF. It throws:

> ValueError: Unknown field for ProcessRequest: document_type

So, I figured I need to add this:

```
# Import the base64 encoding library.
import base64

# Pass the image data to an encoding function.
def encode_image(image):
    with open(image, "rb") as image_file:
        encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
    return encoded_string
```

So, I tried:

```
# Function to encode the image as base64
def encode_image(image_path):
    with open(image_path, "rb") as image_file:
        encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read()).decode("utf-8")
    return encoded_string

# File path to the JPEG image
image_path = "merged_images/fake.jpeg"

# Encode the image as base64
encoded_image = encode_image(image_path)

# Call the process_document_sample function
process_document_sample(
    project_id="99999FAKE",
    location="us",
    processor_id="99999FAKE",
    file_path=encoded_image
)
```

Unfortunately, that leads to:

> OSError: [Errno 63] File name too long:

I guess that's because you only need base64 for a JSON-based request, but that still leaves me with the original error.

Comment: How about changing your file name by usig os.rename?

Comment: @Lara19 Thanks, but the file name error is just because it thought the full insanely-long base64 encoded string was a file name.

Comment: Update: I've found a work-around using a different method, but not a direct answer.

Comment: @kiranmathew Thank you. Since I have worked around the issue I am not currently in a position to test the solution but I have upvoted it since it looks correct.

Answer (score 2):

For your requirement, you can consider the below code:

```
from google.api_core.client_options import ClientOptions
from google.cloud import documentai


PROJECT_ID = "my-project"
LOCATION = "us"  
PROCESSOR_ID = "processorid"  
FILE_PATH = "sample_image.jpeg"
MIME_TYPE = "image/jpeg"

docai_client = documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceClient(
    client_options=ClientOptions(api_endpoint=f"{LOCATION}-documentai.googleapis.com")
)

RESOURCE_NAME = docai_client.processor_path(PROJECT_ID, LOCATION, PROCESSOR_ID)
with open(FILE_PATH, "rb") as image:
    image_content = image.read()

raw_document = documentai.RawDocument(content=image_content, mime_type=MIME_TYPE)
request = documentai.ProcessRequest(name=RESOURCE_NAME, raw_document=raw_document)
result = docai_client.process_document(request=request)
document_object = result.document
print("\n Document processing complete.\n")
print(f"Text: {document_object.text}")
```

**RESULT**
[image]

In the above example, I gave a jpeg image as input,`mime type` as `image/jpeg` and got the expected result. According to the Google cloud documentation `Documentation AI` is supporting the jpeg format also. For more information, you can refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/file-types).

Comment: This should be fine. The issue was that you are sending the full encoded base64 string as the file path, instead of the `rawDocument` content.

See the documentation for more code samples about sending processing requests.

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request